# Ninject in MVC 5 Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

If I want to use Ninject to create a service in my HomeController, I can do:

```
    IUserService _userService;

    public HomeController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public ActionResult SomeMethod()
    {
        userService.DoSomething();
       return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        //I don't use the service here
       return View();
    }
```

However, say I only need to use the service in just on of my controller methods (SomeMethod) - the constructor above fires for ALL methods in the controller (even SomeOtherMethod). Seems wasteful?

If I change it to the following, it works up until the view is returned, then I get an error (as detailed in [Getting "MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface" when binding generic interface to repository with Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881762/getting-missingmethodexception-cannot-create-an-instance-of-an-interface-when)):

```
    public HomeController()
    {
    }

    public ActionResult SomeMethod(IUserService userService)
    {
        userService.DoSomething();
       return View();
    }
```

Is it just that there's no overhead of putting ninject in the constructor - so it's OK? Or do I need one of the other ninject methods of Injection?

Thanks.

Comment: Instating a class is very cheap (unless, of course, you do a lot of work in the constructor, but you could do it lazily). Making injection action wise will only bring more problems in the long run.

Comment: Yah. Just inject a `Lazy<T>` where `T` is your service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that if you don't need your dependency in your other methods, then your class has too many responsibilities and you should probably redesign it so that those methods are in a different class.

Good design in MVC follows the Single Responsibility Principle, which says that objects should have very limited responsibilities.  So if your class requires the user service, but doesn't need it for some functions, what exactly would those functions be doing that would be part of the same responsibility?

Regardless, when using dependency injection, your dependencies should be cheap.  They should not do any real work in their constructors, and only do their initialization upon use.  This way, even if you have a dependency that you're not using for a particular method, the overhead is not very high.

Having said that, there are any number of optimizations you can make at runtime.  For instance, you can configure Ninject to NOT instantiate certain dependencies under various conditions, so you could say that when the current action is Foo, don't create a user service, even if it has the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to late-create the `IUserService` you can add [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory) and then **constructor** inject `Func<IUserService`, `Lazy<IUserService>` or even some interface-Factory `IUserServiceFactory` (which is bound using `Bind<IUserServiceFactory>().ToFactory()`) into the constructor and use it in the `SomeMethod` Action. For Example:

```
Func<IUserService> _userServiceFactory;

public HomeController(Func<IUserService> userServiceFactory)
{
    _userServiceFactory= userServiceFactory;
}

public ActionResult SomeMethod()
{
    IUserService userService = _userServiceFactory();
    userService.DoSomething();
   return View();
}

public ActionResult SomeOtherMethod()
{
    //I don't use the service here
   return View();
}
```

However, you should consider that creating a proper [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) which instantiates the entire object graph as soon as possible is good practice. By default, you also should only optimize for performance when you've got good reasons to (this means, you've measured that exactly this action helps improving the performance). But often times it's rather an issue of design than just of performance: is your controller really adhering to [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) ([SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) in particular)?

Comment: I should note that instantiating the entire object graph is generally only good practice in web applications.  In other applications, like long running desktop or windows services, instantiating the entire graph may be prohibitive and wasteful, not to mention the fact that you need to more finely manage object lifetimes because the app is long running.

Comment: @Erik Funkenbusch yeah i think the subject is somewhat controversial. There's pro's and con's to instant creation at startup. Longer startup time and wasting resource is certainly a downside. Faster feedback in case of invalid bindings is an advantage on the oder side. I still believe in everyone having to make their own choices.

Comment: Well, many cases this is flat out bad.. For instance, EF contexts are designed to be destroyed right after use.  If you inject these, you want them created each time you do an action, not when the app starts up.  You could probably rationalize this with the Composition Root philosophy by saying you have multiple Composition Roots, and that these roots are dynamically created as needed.

Comment: Yes you're totally correct about the EFcontexts / UnitOfWork / Sessions. These need to have a much more "scoped" lifetime, even in an application otherwise adhering to single composition root. However I disagree with you on "multi composition root rationalization". One point of the composition root is that it defines how to map types and basically configures the application. The use of `UnitOfWork` has nothing to do with that.

Comment: I didn't say anything about UnitOfWork.  Composition Root is not just about defining mappings, it's the root of your object graph.. as in the root of the composition of your object graph.  If you're going to have multiple object graphs, then you need multiple composition roots.

Comment: As far as i know an EF `DbContext` represents a unit of work. Also i explicitly wrote that mapping is one (of several) points of composition root. As far as i know in a single process all objects are in effect created by the entry point (`main` method), as such the entry point is the composition root and it's impossible to have multiple "composition roots". I think multiple IoC-Container instances is used b/c a framework prohibits real IoC-Container Composition root setup or for specific design choices, but not because it's impossible to create an application with a single composition root.